# How to use a vector to classify values in R?

Tags: r, probability

I have just started using the probabilities on R and I would like to classify the data according to their values.

```
set.seed(1)
w<-runif(150,0,10)
```

I'd also like to use a vector to classify in 3 categories low(for values < 4), medium(between 4 and 6), high for the rest.

Thank you in advance.

*I apologize for bad English (I'm french)*

Comment: `z <- cut(w, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 6, Inf), c('low', 'medium', 'high'))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know how to count the number of "low", "medium", and "high" ? Thanks you in advance

Comment: `table(z)` will give you the counts.